# Why does my Launcher think that a Terminal is a Thunderbird window?

Tags: command-line, unity, launcher, thunderbird

My recent Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade failed in the middle and required some repair before appearing to complete successfully.  Ever since, however, Ubuntu seems to think that a new Terminal instance is a Thunderbird window.  See images:

Part of screen before Terminal is opened

[image]

Part of screen after Terminal is opened

[image]

You'll see that:

- after the Terminal is opened, a white triangle has appeared to the left of the Thunderbird icon, even though Thunderbird is not running
- the Terminal icon does not have any little triangles
- in the menu bar, the application name is given as "Thunderbird Mail", although all of the menus are correct and appropriate for a Terminal window.

How might I clean this up?  I assume that it's corruption in my system rather than a more general bug:  I can't find anything similar elsewhere.

Many thanks!

Comment: Very peculiar issue, but I'd say it's a general bug.

Answer (score 1):

**How might I clean this up?**

It's not Gnome-terminal that is stored, on the launcher (through some fluke), but Thunderbird with a wrong image displayed.

The remedy is to right click the Launcher image of the Gnome-terminal icon and click `Unlock from Launcher`.

Now hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.  Now right click the image on the Launcher and Click `lock to Launcher`.

Reboot your computer (or run `unity` from the terminal) to flush the Launcher's Icon cache.

Comment: I have unlocked both Gnome-terminal and Thunderbird from the Launcher.  If I now hit Ctrl-Alt-T, then a terminal window opens, but the icon that appears in the Launcher is Thunderbird, complete with Thunderbird left-button options such as "Compose New Message".

It's as if the identities of Gnome-terminal and Thunderbird have got tangled at a moderately deep level.  Do we know any way to clean this up?

Comment: I would suggest unlocking both Thunderbird and Gnome-terminal from the Launcher and making a new one for both of them.

Comment: What do I do to make new ones?  
(I can find both gnome-terminal.desktop and thunderbird.desktop in /usr/share/applications.  Neither is obviously corrupt; desktop-file-validate throws up a number of syntax errors but nothing that looks like it should be fatal.)

Comment: Remove the current flawed icons from the launcher by right clicking and clicking the `Unlock from Launcher` option.  Add new ones to the launcher by starting the application, then right click on the icon on the launcher and clicking `Lock to Launcher`.

Comment: Ah yes - but when I start Gnome-terminal, I don't get a Terminal icon on the launcher.  Instead,  I get a Thunderbird icon complete with Thunderbird menu options on right-click.

Comment: * I see that my earlier comment referred to "left-button options" which is incorrect... I meant right-button *

Comment: Does this behavior exist between reboots?  When is the last time you rebooted your computer?  Try running `unity` from the commandline.  Do you still have the wrong icon after that command?

Comment: D'oh!  Rebooting fixed it (at least until further notice).  Sorry to have wasted your time.  If I knew how to do a red-faced emoticon, I would.

Comment: You didn't waste my time.  Thanks for being so quick to give feedback to help me identify the culprit.  I updated the Answer.  Sorry I didn't include this in the answer originally, even though I suspected it.  I was sure, under most circumstances rebooting is the first thing a person will do to fix a glitch.  I thought you had already done that.   If the answer works as is, you might consider marking it solved by clicking on the gray checkmark next to the anser so that others can benefit.